# Is it possible to pass props from a Client Component to a Server Component in Next.js?

Tags: next.js

I am wanting to be able to "initialize" a few components with data that will hardly ever change (so the data would do well being cached) and after switching to Next.js 13 I looked into server components and was thinking I could use a server component to generate these components. I then realized that I did not know if it was possible to pass props such as function handlers to server components. One example of a component I am making would be a component responsible for showing the available pick-up times that a store has and allowing the user to select one from a select HTML input. Would this be possible with a server component or is there a way with Next.js to cache the data so that the component that relies on the data is rendered as fast as a statically generated page?